# using regex in microsoft sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I copy the data based on an condition and I insert it into the same table with a different `ID`.As follows:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table ON
 INSERT INTO Table (ID,GroupID,Name,link,etc..)
SELECT 
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table) + ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY ID),
     10500,
     Name,
     link    
FROM Table
WHERE GroupID =10400
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table OFF
```

this gives me the following table

```
**ID    | GroupID  | Link**
3       | 10400    |/testsDatas/10400/Uploads
4       | 10500    |/testsDatas/10400/Uploads  //this is a new entry that the above query will enter.
```

The question I have is when the above query copies a row how can I change `/testsDatas/10400/` to `/testsDatas/10500/`?

so that it looks like the following

```
**ID        | GroupID  | Link**
    3       | 10400    |/testsDatas/10400/Uploads
    4       | 10500    |/testsDatas/10500/Uploads  //desired output
```

there is mulitple rows of data,with more columns that I did not add.How do I achieve this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  eg `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @wBob Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64)   Jul  6 2017 07:55:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would using [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) work for you?  A simple example:]

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( ID INT, name VARCHAR(50), link VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
    ( 3, '10400', '/testsDatas/10400/Uploads' )

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT
    (
    SELECT MAX(ID) 
    FROM @table
    ) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID),
    10500,
    REPLACE( link, name, 10500 )
FROM @table


SELECT *
FROM @table
```

My results:

[image: Results]